# Sharing code in respond_to blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following `before_filter`:

```
  def find_current_membership
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.html { @current_membership = @group.memberships.for(@current_user) }
      wants.rss  {}
      wants.js   { @current_membership = @group.memberships.for(@current_user) }
    end
  end
```

I would like to share the code for the HTML and JS blocks.  Is there a better way than just throwing the code into a method?  I was hoping this would work:

```
  def find_current_membership
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.rss  {}
      wants.all  { @current_membership = @group.memberships.for(@current_user) }
    end
  end
```

But alas, it did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, it looks like `find_current_membership` is your `before_filter` method, is that right? eg:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_current_membership
  ...
```

I think it's a bit non-standard to use `respond_to` inside a `before_filter`, they are meant to just do something and render on failure. It seems to me like you want something more like this

```
    class SomeController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :find_current_membership

      def some_action
        # stuff, or maybe nothing
      end

   private
      def find_current_membership
         @current_membership = @group.memberships.for(@current_user) unless request.format.rss?
      end
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could probably do something like:

```
before_filter :only => :find_current_membership do |c|
    load_current_membership if not request.format.rss?
end
```

Alternatively you could use the request.format.rss? in your controller method to conditionally load the memberships.

Either way your first step should be to refactor that into a method.

Answer (score 1):

How about this simple solution!?

```
def find_current_membership
  @current_membership = @group.memberships.for(@current_user)
  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.html
    wants.rss  {}
    wants.js
  end
end
```